# Why do two processes that perform matrix multiplications run slower in parallel than in succession?

Tags: c++, multithreading, process, armadillo

I have a program that runs a linear algebra experiment (using Armadillo library in C++). I need to run this program many times, so was going to execute multiple processes in parallel (up to my available resources). However, even when running only two experiments in parallel, both processes slow down a disproportionate amount - they're at least 10x slower than when executed sequentially.

I have managed to reduce my code down to where the problem occurs, and it appears to be where I multiply a matrix by a vector. Here is a reproducible example. This runs infinitely and prints the elapsed number of seconds every 1000th iteration of multiplying a matrix by a vector.

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

  mat A = randn(1500,1500);
  vec y = randn(1500);
  vec values;

  long its = 0;
  while (true) {

    values = A*y;

    // print time once in a while
    if (++its % 1000 == 0) {
      long secondsElapsed = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(chrono::steady_clock::now() - begin).count();
      cout << "secs elapsed by iteration " << its << ": " << secondsElapsed << endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled/linked with:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -larmadillo -std=c++11
```

When running a single process of this program, in a terminal, output is:

```
secs elapsed by iteration 1000: 1
secs elapsed by iteration 2000: 2
secs elapsed by iteration 3000: 3
...
```

When running two processes of this program (in two different terminals), output for process 1 is:

```
secs elapsed by iteration 1000: 24
secs elapsed by iteration 2000: 48
secs elapsed by iteration 3000: 74
...
```

and process 2 output is similar. The process is 24 times slower when the second process is running as well.

The 'top' utility on Linux is showing 400% cpu for each of the two processes, so 800% in total (I have 4 cores 8 threads). 0.3% of my memory taken by each of the two processes.

Why may this be happening, and how can I fix it? I'm not certain how to debug this myself, but want to learn, so it would be great if someone could provide some tips for how to debug a situation like this in their answer!

Platform details: Linux 3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64, 4 cores / 8 threads, 8Gb RAM. g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36). ARMA version: 8.300.2 (Tropical Shenanigans).

Comment: The keyword for further investigation: *CPU cache*.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few things.

You're not compiling with optimizations. Use `-O2` and `-march=native`

It looks like Armadillo uses BLAS to do vector-matrix multiplication. The secret may lie there. It sounds like the library is already set up to use all the cores; you may not be unable to squeeze more performance out by multiprocessing. Ok... well like you said, you have a hyper-threaded quad-core x86_64 and you want to use 8 logical cores instead of just 4. But remember that hyper-threading works by letting 2 threads use the processor at the same time. It *can* double performance since there are usually a lot of leftover arithmetic units. But if the BLAS kernel uses all the SIMD units (or just makes really good use of the available arithmetic units) on all 4 cores, a second instance running concurrently won't have any hardware left for itself and may end up only getting in the way through context switching, which messes up hardware pipelines and causes cache misses.

I'm trying to think of a way you could test this. If you have access to other machines with different numbers of physical cores you might see a pattern. An ideal debugging control would be the ability to tell BLAS how many cores to use, but I'm not sure if that's available.

CPU arch would be good to know here as well as BLAS version (if you are indeed using BLAS).

You didn't mention any profiling you've done. If you haven't done profiling, now would be a great time! If this section is the bottleneck by a lot, you could benefit from some GPU acceleration. Or if it's the bottleneck but only by a little bit, you could pipeline other parts of the program to keep this section fed with data. Or you could always just be content with the current speed if the run-time is reasonable.